# How to register ngrx effects in a standalone component?

Tags: angular, ngrx

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-standlone-component',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    // EffectsModule.forFeature([MyStandAloneComponentRelatedEffects]), // => type mismatch
  },
  providers: [
    // importProvidersFrom(EffectsModule.forFeature([MyStandAloneComponentRelatedEffects])), // => type mismatch
  ]
})
```

Any suggestion how I can register the effects in a standalone component?

Side facts:
The component is lazy loaded and I really want to register the effects only if the component is alive. Since this works with a lazy loaded SCAM I hope I can find a solution for the equivalent standalone approach.

Comment: See https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#using-the-standalone-api-1

Comment: Thanks for your fast response @AndrewAllen. But that's not my preferred approach since I need to move store stuff to the routing. But yes, this works. The disadvantage is IMHO that the effects are registered if the component is loaded or not...

Answer (score 0):

Effects are not bound to the component's lifecycle.
There's a new functional `createEffect`, but I suppose that this isn't what you're looking for. https://ngrx.io/api/effects/createEffect#functional-effects

If you need an effect that's bound to the components' lifecycle, you can also take a look at component store. Which does exactly what you're looking for (I think).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @timdeschryver. No, a component store is not what I'm looking for. I guess I need to go a bit deeper:
I have a global store (with entities btw.) and a feature component that dispatches an "entered" action. To not violate the open close principle I want to implement feature effects that maps these "entered" action to a "loadTriggered" action. So the store doesn't need to know anything about feature components.